# Hide content with Javascript on mouseover event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Normally I would use CSS to control styles but in this particular case I can't.

I have many `onmouseover` events on `<li>` tags as you see in example below.

```
<li onmouseover="document.getElementById('vid').style.display='none'">1</li>
<li onmouseover="document.getElementById('vid').style.display='none'">2</li>
<li onmouseover="document.getElementById('vid').style.display='none'">3</li>
```

What I want to do is instead of writing `onmouseover="..."` for each `<li>` just have this style event controlled from `<script></script>` element so that I have less code on the page.

Can this be done? I don't know javascript enough code this `<script> ???? </script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('li:first-child').mouseover(function(){
   $('#vid').hide();
 });
  
  $('li:last-child').mouseover(function(){
   $('#vid').show();
 });
});
```

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
}

li{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover{
  border-color: green;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Hide content</li>
  <li>Show content</li>
</ul>

<div id="vid">Here is content.</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('mouseover', 'li', function() {
    $("#vid").hide();
  });
});
```